# In Javascript is there a way to stop an exception from ending a .some() or .forEach() loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, exception

**Environment:** Node.js, axios package

**Question:** In Javascript is there a way to stop an exception from ending a `.some()` or `forEach()` loop?

**Background:** I'm using a `some()` loop to process an Array.  On the first match a `return true` statement stops the loop.  Inside of the loop is an async `.get()` request.  Certain responses including error responses indicate a match.  Unfortunately when an exception is thrown it stops the `some()` loop.

**Example:**

```
const axios = require('axios');

let startURL = 'example.com';

let httpsWwwURL = `https://www.${ startURL }`;
let httpsURL = `https://${ startURL }`;
let httpWwwURL = `http://www.${ startURL }`;
let httpURL = `http://${ startURL }`;

let URLArray = [httpsWwwURL, httpsURL, httpWwwURL, httpURL];

let axiosResult = false;
let okResult = new RegExp('OK', 'i');

URLArray.some(async function(element) {

    await axios.get(element)
        .then(function(response) {
            if(String(response.status).includes('2')) axiosResult = true;
            if(response.statusText.match(okResult)) axiosResult = true;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            if(error.response !== undefined) axiosResult = true;
        })
        .finally(async function() {
            if(axiosResult === true) {
                console.log('hooray it worked');
            }
        });
    if(axiosResult === true) return true;

});
```

Comment: the way to stop an exception from preventing one of these functions from "stopping" is to handle all exceptions

Comment: @ Jaromanda X I wrapped the `await axios.get()` block in a try / catch but it still broke.  Did I wrap the wrong code segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't ending early because of an exception, it's ending because `.some` doesn't work with async functions.

It's going to call your async function for the first element of the array, and then your async function will return a promise. Promises are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so the `.some` is immediately done executing and will not move on to the second element of the array, even if the promise later resolves to false.

You will not be able to use `.some`, `.forEach`, etc if your operations are asynchronous. Instead, you might try a `for ... of` loop.

```
(async () {
  let URLArray = [httpsWwwURL, httpsURL, httpWwwURL, httpURL];

  let axiosResult = false;
  let okResult = new RegExp('OK', 'i');

  for (const element of URLArray) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(element);
      if(String(response.status).includes('2')) axiosResult = true;
      if(response.statusText.match(okResult)) axiosResult = true;
    } catch (error) {
      if(error.response !== undefined) axiosResult = true;
    }

    if (axiosResult) {
      console.log('hooray, it worked');
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```